# Is it possible to use an single image from an array of images in an Maps InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I have the following functions which specify and deliver the output of an array of images that are retrieved from a library database through its API (initially given as addresses in JSON format).

```
        function processImages(index, troveItem){
                for(var i in availableImages){
                    if(troveItem.identifier[0].value.indexOf(availableImages[i].url_pattern) >= 0){
                        console.log("Trove URL "+troveItem.identifier[0].value+"  Pattern: "+availableImages[i]["url_pattern"]);
                        availableImages[i].numImages++;
                        availableImages.totalimages++;
                        availableImages[i]["images"].push(troveItem.identifier[0].value);
                    }
                }
        }
 ////


        function printImages(){
            $("#output").append("<h3>Image Search Results</h3>");
            for(var i in availableImages){
                if(availableImages[i]["url_pattern"]=="nla.gov.au" && availableImages[i]["numImages"]>0){
                    printNLAImages();
                }
               }
 /////

        function printNLAImages(){
            $("#output").append("<h3>National Library of Australia</h3><p>"
                    +availableImages["nla"]["numImages"]+" images found from <a href='http://"
                    +availableImages["nla"]["url_pattern"]+"'>"
                    +availableImages["nla"]["url_pattern"]+"</a></p>");

            for (var i in availableImages["nla"]["images"]){
                $("#output").append("<img src='"+availableImages["nla"]["images"][i]+"-v'>");

            }

        }
```

Now this outputs to a `<div>` with the id "output". 
Is there a way I can make the first array item of these images into a? variable? or something I can use within an `<img>` tag of the Google Maps API InfoWindow content string?
Is this possible, and what would be the best way to go about it if so?